# What's the point of automatic properties that define both get and set in apex?

Tags: apex-code

It makes sense to me why you might want to have a property like

```
public string var {get;}
```

to make it read-only, or

```
public string var {set;}
```

to make var write-only (although I'm not sure where that would be useful). But what does

```
public string var {get; set;}
```

get you that making var a bog-standard variable doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really. I prefer the explicit:

```
public String myVar {get; private set;}
```

to simply omitting the set. It's really just a shorthand convention of the classic:

```
public String myVar
{
   get
   {
      return myVar;
   }
   set(String s)
   {
      myVar = s;
   }
}
```

When in Rome...

Answer (score 0):

It makes it visible to the VisualForce page.

```
public String var;
```

Won't let you get to the var variable from Visualforce.

I.e.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!var}">
```

will fail.